# Print function not printing in order

Tags: python, function, printing, output

```
print('*'*11,'Welcome to Salad Bar','*'*11,'\n')
print('\t1.Order Salad')
print('\t2.checkout')      
print('\t3.Quit')
option = input('Select your option(1-4): \n')
if option == 1:
    print('Salad menu\n1.Vegetarian-$10.99\n2.Seafood-16.99\n3.Protein-14.99')
```

When I ran the code, here is the output

```
Select your option(1-4): 
*********** Welcome to Salad Bar *********** 

    1.Order Salad
    2.checkout
    3.Quit
```

Not sure why the "welcome to salad bar...." is not printed first.

Comment: I think it's because of the input. You can add welcome to the salad bar as a multiline string. Try it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the same result, on my end everything runs sequentially - as intended.

Comment: Thanks @Maneth, I will try the multi line string

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the version of python you're running? I'm on 3.7.4 and cannot seem to recreate

```
*********** Welcome to Salad Bar *********** 

1.Order Salad
2.checkout
3.Quit
Select your option(1-4):
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code in VS Code, in Jupyter Notebook, and from a Windows command prompt.  In all three cases, I got the 'Welcome to Salad Bar' line first, as you expected.  So there might be something wrong with your Python setup.

If you are not using an environment such as VS Code, that highlights tricky errors such as not-quite-right indentation and such, I suggest that you do so.  I have found this very helpful, and it might help you here.  VS Code is free and was recommended by a friend, and there are other free environments and editors out there with similar features.

There is also one small issue with your code:  The "if option == 1" clause will never be True because the input command returns a string.  It will work if you say this:

if option == str(1):

- Eliot

P.S.  I see that you are new to Stackoverflow.  Me too!  This is the first time I have offered an answer.  Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eliot very helpful, I will  running it in VS code, and concerning the input I will convert that to int. I appreciate

Comment: I am using version 3.9

Comment: Matt - In VS Code, you can set a break point at the offending print line (your first line).  If you run the script in Debug mode, it will stop there, and then you can single-step the execution and see what happens at each line.  Another person replied that your input command might be messing up your display, and that's one thing you would be able to determine with single-stepping.

Comment: Thanks, Eliot, I greatly appreciate. I ran the code in VS Code and is now running fine as I wanted.